# Ignore apt-get postinstall scripts automatically

Tags: apt, dpkg

We have a script which install multiple packages,

We need to skip any actions in postinstall scripts.

I tried this:

```
touch /var/lib/dpkg/info/packagename.postinst
chmod +x /var/lib/dpkg/info/packagename.postinst
/usr/bin/apt-get --force-yes --assume-yes install packagename
```

But it seems to ovewrite /var/lib/dpkg/info/packagename.postinst

Answer (score 30):

Apt gets `dpkg` to extract the packages afresh each time it installs. You'll have to use `dpkg` directly and get it to split the process:

```
apt-get download <package>
sudo dpkg --unpack <package>*.deb
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.postinst -f
sudo dpkg --configure <package>
sudo apt-get install -yf #To fix dependencies
```