# Skip configure for one package during apt install

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg

I currently have a 14.04 machine with a broken package (A), such that when it tries to `dpkg --configure` it hangs for hours and then fails. The details are unimportant, and are not what I'm trying to fix here.

Whenever I try to install/upgrade something else (B) via `apt`, it tries to run the configuration for package A again.

Is there a way to make `apt` skip the `dpkg --configure` for package A, but otherwise proceed as normal when installing new package B?

The other alternative I can see is to manually get and install the `.deb` for package B instead of using `apt`.

Comment: "The other alternative I can see is to manually get and install the .deb instead of using apt" ... nope. `dpkg` will configure any packages it tries to install. Depending on the "unimportant" details, you may actually be looking to skip maintainer scripts: https://askubuntu.com/q/482928/158442

Comment: @muru yes, it will configure the package I am trying to install, but not the existing broken one, right?

Comment: No, I believe it won't try to configure other packages (that needs `dpkg --configure -a`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an option to do this, so I had to manually manage the packages instead.

Use `apt download PKG` to get a `.deb` file, then install it with `sudo dkpg -i FILE`.

There may be an error "dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of PGK". In which case, the listed packages also need to be dowloaded, and all installed together (e.g. `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try purging the package via apt before trying to install something else?

`sudo apt purge package`

Comment: No, because that would uninstall the package and delete all its data.