# Where is the unpacked content of a .deb file when using the "--unpack" option of dpkg?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, deb

About the `dpkg` command, a few tutorials do mention of the `--unpack` option. According with
[jammy (1) dpkg.1](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/dpkg.1.html) it indicates

```
--unpack package-file...
   Unpack the package, but don't configure it. If --recursive or -R option is specified,
   package-file must refer to a directory instead.
```

Well just how testing, from the [MySQL APT Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) page it is possible to get the `mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb` file. So in the `Downloads` directory I executed the command:

```
sudo dpkg --unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb
```

It works with the following message

```
(Reading database ... 238377 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-apt-config_0.8.24-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-apt-config (0.8.24-1) over (0.8.24-1) ...
```

Even when MySQL is installed.

**Question**

- Where is the *unpacked* the content of a `.deb` file?

A simple execution of the `ls` command only shows the current `.deb` file. I expected a kind of *extraction*. I am assuming a kind of default directory or other something else was used.

If with the `-c` option, it is possible to see the directories of the `.deb` file I am assuming that the `--unpack` option unpacks the `.deb` file - if my assumption is incorrect about the latter, please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the part immediately about `--unpack` in the manpage (for `--install`):

> Installation consists of the following steps:
>
> 1. Extract the control files of the new package.
> 2. If another version of the same package was installed before the new installation,    execute prerm script of the old package.
> 3. Run preinst script, if provided by the package.
> 4. Unpack the new files, and at the same time back up the old files, so that if    something goes wrong, they can be restored.
> 5. If another version of the same package was installed before the new installation,    execute the postrm script of the old package.
>    Note that this script is executed after    the preinst script of the
>    new package, because new files are written at the same time    old
>    files are removed.
> 6. Configure the package. See --configure for detailed information about how this is    done.

Step 4 would seem to indicate that to *unpack* means to put the files in the package wherever they are supposed to be in the final state of the system. So if the package was supposed to install a `/usr/bin/foo` or an `/etc/bar/baz` file, then unpacking will put the corresponding files at those locations.

If you wanted to extract the files to the current directory or something like that instead of extracting them to the final installation targets, then the option is `-x` or `--extract`:

```
-x, --extract archive directory
   Extract the files contained by package.

-X, --vextract archive directory
   Extract and display the filenames contained by a package.
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - about _So if the package was supposed to install a /usr/bin/foo or an /etc/bar/baz file ..._ for that paths: Are they the ones listed through the `-L` parameter, right? - It seems that use `--unpack` directly is useful to reput/reset some files if they were either deleted or overridden - Am I correct with that assumption?

Comment: Yes and yes. It's also useful if you want more control over the execution of the maintainer scripts (preinst, postinst, etc.) since you can unpack, then modify the scripts, then run them.

Comment: Wondered why the `--unpack` option from the beginning did not include this information about to _reput/reset_ these files.

Comment: Just being curious about _since you can unpack, then modify the scripts, then run them_ - therefore: unpack with `--unpack` (ok) - edit with nano/vim (ok) - but: How to install using directly the unpacked edited files?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking there. Install what exactly?

Comment: If you use `sudo dpkg -i mysql.deb` it installs mysql, right? - if you use `dpkg --unpack mysql.deb` it unpacks the installation files of the `.deb` file to some explicit paths, you can edit the installation files (as you wrote in your first comment) - so: How do you accomplish the installation process through the unpacked files? in this point the `.deb` file can't be used because it has the original installation files without any edition.

Comment: I said you can edit [the maintainer scripts](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#maintscripts). I'm not sure what you mean by installation files here - please clarify. The maintainer scripts are for doing some configuration (e.g., creating a user, or asking the admin to select some configurable option like the mysql root password, etc.) and the process I talked about is for manipulating such scripts before they're run. See, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/482936/158442

Comment: Huge Thanks for the 2 links. Now I understand the process. I understood in other way.